# View pager with fragment calling method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**ViewPager** call every fragment Rest api calling method
I have 3 **Fragments**  A , B , C
When I moved from Fragment A to Fragment C then Fragment B method is also called same as when i moved from Fragment C to B then Fragment A is called below code.
I have already tried

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `viewpager` has this behavior to load one minimum next fragment , To avoid calling the api  without the user actually on the fragment you can override "setUserVisibilityHint (boolean visibleToUser)" and call your api only if "visibleToUser" becomes true

```
@Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
 super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
     //callRequestApi 
    }
    else {
     //DoNothing
      }
    }
```

Comment: setUserVisibleHint method calling before onCreateView().

Comment: yes just call the request in isVisibleToUser and not within onCreateView()

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand you

Comment: update code snippets for better understand this issue.